# How to get the second to last element in a Vector in R

Tags: r

I am trying to get the second to last element of a Vector into another vector. For an example see this data set

Vector A

```
7.31 15.54  9.79  4.24  9.01  6.26 12.05  5.16 11.13  7.69  6.42 13.65 11.17 11.04  6.80  7.15 11.52 10.14 10.07 8.30
```

I want to Create a

Vector B

```
  15.54  9.79  4.24  9.01  6.26 12.05  5.16 11.13  7.69  6.42 13.65 11.17 11.04  6.80  7.15 11.52 10.14 10.07 8.30
```

However I don't want to use

`B<-A[2:20]`

because with the time last element number will change(increases)

```
A[1:tail(A,n=1)]
[1]  7.31 15.54  9.79  4.24  9.01  6.26 12.05  5.16
```

This gives half of the data. Just 8 elements.
Also tried

```
 B<-A[1:last(A)]
 print(B)
[1]  7.31 15.54  9.79  4.24  9.01  6.26 12.05  5.16
```

it gives only first few elements. why?

the answer I expect is

```
15.54  9.79  4.24  9.01  6.26 12.05  5.16 11.13  7.69  6.42 13.65 11.17 11.04  6.80  7.15 11.52 10.14 10.07 8.30
```

Comment: Try `A[2:length(A)]`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your Code works. Humbly appreciated. can some one explain why the functions I used gave me half data.

Comment: Or A[-1] works too.

Comment: @DataMan `A[1:last(A)]` is the same as `A[1:8.30]` as `8.30` is the last element of `A`.  Hence `A[1:8]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to leave one element from the vector `A`. You can simply write `B=tail(A,-1)`
where `-1` leaves the first element.

Comment: That's right, `tail()` is around 1/3 slower though.

Answer (score 3):

The title is quite ambiguous, I thought it was going to be the second to last element in the sense of the second one from the end!

I'm curious to know why nobody answered with the seemingly obvious:

```
B <- A[-1]
```

maybe negative indexing uses tail() in any case? Hope I didn't completely misunderstand the question!!

Answer (score 2):

Consider vector `v` containing ten elements.

```
v <- c(7.31, 15.54, 9.79, 4.24, 9.01, 6.26, 12.05, 5.16, 11.13, 7.69)
```

To get the 2<sup>nd</sup> to the last (i.e. 10<sup>th</sup>) element, you would write hard-coded,

```
v[2:10]
# [1] 15.54  9.79  4.24  9.01  6.26 12.05  5.16 11.13  7.69
```

which means inside the `[` brackets you define the *number* of the element.

On the other hand,

```
v[2:tail(v, 1)]
# [1] 15.54  9.79  4.24  9.01  6.26 12.05
```

gives you different result, because `tail()` gives you the *value* of an element, which is in our example:

```
tail(v, 1)
# [1] 7.69
```

So actually you're saying,

```
v[2:7.69]
# [1] 15.54  9.79  4.24  9.01  6.26 12.05
```

which is `v[2:8]` because `7.69` will be coerced `as.integer(7.69)` which yields `8`.

You want to dynamically get the number of the last element, a task for `length()`, so what you want to do is:

```
v[2:length(v)]
# [1] 15.54  9.79  4.24  9.01  6.26 12.05  5.16 11.13  7.69
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Regarding short lists or vectors:

Both `tail(A,-1)` and `A[2:length(A)]` work the same for lists/vectors with **length≥2**, but **0-length** and **1-length** lists/vectors yield dissimilar results, favoring `tail(A,-1)`.

```
Q0 = list()
Q1 = list(10)
C0 = c()
C1 = c(10)

tail(Q0 , -1)
# list()

tail(Q1 , -1)
# list()

tail(C0 , -1)
# NULL

tail(C1 , -1)
# numeric(0)

Q0[2:length(Q0)]
# [[1]]
# NULL
# 
# [[2]]
# NULL

Q1[2:length(Q1)]
# [[1]]
# NULL
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 10

C0[2:length(C0)]
# NULL

C1[2:length(C1)]
# NA 10
```

This is especially important if you try to iterate over all elements, starting the second one:

```
for (item in C1[2:length(C1)]) {next} # would execute *twice*.
for (item in tail(C1, -1)) {next} # would *not* execute.
```